# HTML & CSS - Interplay Between Text-Decoration:Overline and <sub>

Tags: html, css

When I try to create a square root using the "√" (`&radic;` code) and overline, this generally works until I introduce `<sub>` tags, such as in the following:

```html
v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub></span>
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but I think you can see what I'm seeing:

In Chrome it renders: [image]

Basically, the overline is both broken and lower above the "2" and the "1" within sub tags. It's pretty clear why it's rendering this way, but of course the ideal is to show the equation under an unbroken square root line.  Anyone know a good way to accomplish this? I don't guess I can tell the style to ignore the internal tagging structure, but it seems like this should be achievable within a page using plain old HTML and CSS. Is that not the case?

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? It looks fine to me on iOS Safari.

Comment: Use a `border-top` instead of text-decoration ...?

Comment: Ah, I've  now tried it on Edge/Windows10 and get the broken line as described.

Comment: @CBroe 's suggestion works on Edge/Windows10.

Comment: @CBroe's suggestion also works on Chrome/Win10.

Comment: Personally, and since this is a [tag:css] and [tag:html] question I won't answer below, I'd suggest using [MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html) rather than reinventing the (kinda difficult) wheel. As a demo, I offer [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cbndsa7o/1/).

Comment: Just for reference, Firefox do not break the overline decoration and keeps it straight solid even over "sub"s.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want bit like this

```css
.overline {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.root-expression {
  position: relative;
}

.overline::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.15em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black; /* Adjust the color and style as needed */
}
```

```html
<div>
  v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span class="overline"><span class="root-expression">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to vertical-align the span on its line, then increase of.1  the line height (default is usually 1.2) to set the overline at average top of the √ letter :

here is is the idea , if that makes it clearer:

```css
/* vertical alignment along √ */

span.alignOverline {
  text-decoration: overline;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 1.3
}


/* horizontal alignment along √ */

hr~p span {
  text-indent: -.03em;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* testing different font-size */

p:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  font-size: 2em;
}

p:nth-child(5n + 2) {
  font-size: 4em;
}

p:nth-child(5n + 3) {
  font-size: 6em;
}


/* snippets requirement optionnal */

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span class="alignOverline">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)</span></p>
<p>v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span class="alignOverline">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)</span></p>
<p>v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span class="alignOverline">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)</span></p>
<p>eventually, reset a bit horizontal alignment too:</p>
<hr>
<p>v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span class="alignOverline">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)</span></p>
<p>v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span class="alignOverline">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)</span></p>
<p>v<sub>1</sub> = &radic;<span class="alignOverline">2g(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)</span></p>

<p><b>Tests with font-families to do</b> </p>
```

If you have a lot of this to show on your website, you may also consider using:

- https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax
- https://github.com/asciimath/asciimathml

there is also : https://w3c.github.io/mathml-docs/notes-on-mathml/
average snippet :

```html
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mrow>
    <mi>v1</mi>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mfrac>
      <msqrt>
        <mrow>
          <mi>2</mi>
          <mn>g</mn>
          <mo>(</mo>
          <mi>y</mi>
          <mn>2</mn>
          <mo> - </mo>
          <mi>y</mi>
          <mn>1</mn>
          <mo>)</mo>
        </mrow>
      </msqrt>
    </mfrac>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math to dig further

Comment: Could you extract the MathML suggestion into a separate answer? (IIUC it is not a good practice to give more than one distinct mutually exclusive alternatives in single answer. Anecdotally, I missed there is already MathML already suggested in this answer and nearly submitted a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your problem, albeit there could be a better approach, but I think this should be good enough. I've enclosed the entire equation into a `div` element just to organize it better. Rest of everything is almost same as yours but tidied up. I used another `div` element within for the overline part and gave it the `display: inline;` styling so it'd appear next to the radical symbol, gave it a top border of 1 pixels, used `RGBA` color format and gave black an alpha of 0.5, so it'd match the color of the radical sign. Margin left to get rid of the spacing and so the radical and the overline don't look disconnected. Then used margin left again to add spacing to the left of the numbers.

```html
<div class="equation">
  <span>v<sub>1</sub></span> = &radic;
  <div style="display: inline;border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); margin-left: -4px">
    <span style="margin-left: 4px">2g(y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```